# html, можно ли изменить цвет текста в поле?

Tags: html, css

```css
.field                  { clear:both; text-align: center; }
.field p                { color: white; }
.field-field p          { color: dodgerblue; }
```

```html
<div class=field>
  <h1 align=center>Введите данные для входа в свой профиль:</h1>
  {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
  <br>
  <p>{{ form.nickname.label }}:</p>
  <p><kbd>Введите свой логин, но не более 20 символов</kbd></p>
  <br>

  <div class="field-field">
    <p>{{ form.nickname(size=20) }}</p>
  </div>

  <div class="text-danger">
    {% for error in form.errors.nickname %}
    <span>{{ error }}</span>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>
```

То есть, у меня цвет текста в поле установлен на синий и всё работает, но допустим я нажимаю на поле и выходят значения раньше вводимые и цвет текста становится чёрным. Можно ли изменить это ? Или это значение не меняется?

Comment: Покажите код, без него вам невозможно помочь

Comment: Добавил код....

Comment: какое поле? какой html на месте php? что там? какой должен быть результат?

Answer (score 0):

Если я вас правильно понял, то можно через css-class в поле input.
В том примере, что вы привели, полей ввода нет вообще.

```css
.colortext {
  background-color: #ffe; /* Цвет фона */
  color: #930; /* Цвет текста */
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="colortext">
```

Comment: <div class="field-field">
        <p>{{ form.nickname(size=20) }}</p>
    </div>

Comment: Это поле ввода никнейма

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать так input `.field-field {color:blue;}`